# C++ linker issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, reference

I have this:

a.cpp

```
int localfunction () { return 1; }
int local_symbol = localfunction();
```

b.cpp

```
void thirdfunction () {};
```

main.cpp

```
void main () { thirdfunction (); }
```

When I compile this in a main executable everything works (even with optimizations), and the localfunction is executed at startup even if I don't call it directly.

Now, in Visual C++ and GCC , I put a.cpp and b.cpp in a static library (.lib). localfunction is no more executed/defined.

From what I understand the symbol is detected as "not used" and it is removed. But it sounds weird because:

> - Why it is not removed when I don't use the .lib file?
> - Since the lib is linked in, why the linker blows away the initialization code?

What I'm trying to do to is to have a set of startup function in every .lib file I use that register automatically some data. The main executable should not know what files are linked in nor explicitly reference "localfunction" (/INCLUDE does works but it is not optimal)

BTW : using the various VC++ options (OPT:NOREF , etc..) doesn't solve the problem.

Thank you!
QbProg

Answer (score 3):

A static library is - basically - an library, or archive, of object files compiled from that library's constituent source files.

When the linker uses a static library to resolve dependencies while building an application, it follows a process of looking for object files in the library that help it resolve any undefined symbols in the program. It doesn't automatically include all of the object files in a library.

In your instance the object file generated from `main.cpp` refers to `third_function()`. This dependency can be resolved by linking in the object file generated from `b.cpp`. This object file introduces no further undefined symbols, so the linker can (and does) stop here.

Oh, and for maximum portability `main` should return `int`.

Comment: But when I don't use the lib file the function is kept and executed! Why this differente behavoir?

Comment: That's because when the source isn't in a library, it's part of your application. The linker uses libraries to help complete a program, but it won't include 'unnecessary' object files from libraries. When you specify a non-library object file to include as part of your application the linker will always include that object file even if there is no dependency on it from the rest of your application.

Answer (score 1):

When using gcc and needing a startup function which runs "automatically" before main() runs, I would just use `__attribute__((constructor))`.

Perhaps there is a similar way (pragma?) to define a function in VC++, then you could do some preprocessor macro magic to have a common way to declare those startup functions.

Comment: this attribute is usefoul but it doens't works in the same scenario (lib files).

Answer (score 0):

Your linker will takes steps to reduce the executable size. It will determine that your exe does not use the 'said' function and not include it in its final generated code. Though it also depends on what optimization you're using in your project.

Instead if you wish to dynamically do this, the better alternative is to use LoadLibrary and create a DLL that all your programs can load and dynamically load the function and register what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remeber the old days where size was a premium.

You have a massive maths library with 10,000 different functions.
Now your application uses sin() and you link against libm.a (or -lm).

You definitely do not want to blat your application with 9,999 functions you do not use. So when using static libs it only pulls from the library exactly what is used (nothing more).

On the other hand shared libs are designed so that the whole thing is pulled into memory. Also (though it is not defined in any standard) most dynamic loaders will also run any static initialization code as they are loaded. (Note if you link against them they are generally loaded at application startup).